# meteor: set dynamic heading tag in template

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

This is how I'm using a kind of 'nested' templates to build an article:

```
<template name="example">
    {{ > elements level = 1 }}
</template>

<template name="elements">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
    {{ > elements level = (add ../level)}}
</template>

Template.elements.helpers({
    add: function(level) {
        return level + 1;
    }
})
```

But as you can see, it would always use the `h2` tag, which is not correct. I would like to use the `level`-value to set the correct heading-tag. First level = `h1`, second level = `h2` and so on. How do I do that?